# Change the value of input text with the same name in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want it when I click on a text field, its value is changed by 2.

```
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field' ng-click='changeval()'>
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field' ng-click='changeval()'>
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field' ng-click='changeval()'>
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field' ng-click='changeval()'>

$scope.changeval=function(){
  //set value of input text for 2    
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/0w36h8zm/

Comment: Why do you need to do on this way? Why the inputs must be the same name?

Comment: is an example, is anything that i need

Answer (score 1):

Use Array and Index as parameter if you have a lot of fields

```
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field[0]' ng-click='changeval(0)'>
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field[1]' ng-click='changeval(1)'>
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field[2]' ng-click='changeval(2)'>
<input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field[3]' ng-click='changeval(3)'>
```

**js**

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.field = [];
        $scope.changeval=function(index){
        //change the val for 2;
      $scope.field[index]=2;
    };


});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/0w36h8zm/9/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Value in all the Text fields do this:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.changeval=function(){
    $scope.field=2;
}

});
```

If you want to change the value of the text field on which you click then do this :

```
     <input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field1' ng-click='changeval1()'>
      <input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field2' ng-click='changeval2()'>
           <input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field3' ng-click='changeval3()'>
                <input type='text' name='field[]' ng-model='field4' ng-click='changeval4()'>




     angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modal) {
$scope.changeval1=function(){
$scope.field1=2;
 }

$scope.changeval2=function(){
$scope.field2=2;
}

$scope.changeval3=function(){
$scope.field3=2;
}


$scope.changeval4=function(){
$scope.field4=2;
}
 });
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/0w36h8zm/3/

Comment: thank you, but i need have the same names for the inputs.... i can have n fields..

Comment: They all have the same name = 'field[]'. Only the model and the fucntion changed.